# Making a portion of Rectangle disapear/invisible QML Qt

Tags: qt, qml

I'm making a custom GroupBox in QML and currently I have this

```
Rectangle
{
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "#55aaff"
    Rectangle
    {
        id: combo_box
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "transparent"
        width: parent.width/2
        height: parent.height/2
        opacity: 0.3
        Rectangle
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "transparent"
            border.color: "#ffffff"
            border.width: 1
            radius: 20
        }
    }
    Rectangle
    {
        id: combo_box_title
        anchors.verticalCenter: combo_box.top
        anchors.left: combo_box.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 30
        width: 90
        height: 20
        opacity: 0.3
        color: "#55aaff"
    }
    Text
    {
        id: combo_box_title_text
        anchors.centerIn: combo_box_title
        font.family: "Comic Sans MS"
        font.pointSize: 9
        color: "#e1e100"
        text: "Game Settings"
    }
```

Which show up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wwcS.png)

You can see my ComboBox title has the Rectangle's border in the background. All I want is to remove the part of Rectangle's border that lies behind Title.

Is there a solution to my problem? Or any other way I can have this kind of GroupBox. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try drawing the line using [canvas](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html)

Comment: I think you should remove text in uppercase since it looks disrespectful.

Comment: Is using canvas suitable in this condition? I have a number of rectangles, as you can see in my code, where will I place the canvas? can I draw a rounded line in canvas, as you can see in attached snap? Can you please provide some code? Regards

Comment: @folibis I have removed the uppercase text. I didn't mean to be disrespectful.

Comment: I guess that `Canvas` is what you need as @user2436719 said. [Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-canvas-roundedrect-roundedrect-qml.html) is simple example of painting rectangle with rounded corners that you can start from.

Comment: Just put a rectangle behind the text to cover up a part of the border, it is simpler and will be more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You replace the `Rectangle` with the white border with the `Canvas`:

```
Canvas {
    id: mycanvas
    anchors.fill: parent
    onPaint: {
        var ctx = getContext("2d");
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(120, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(mycanvas.width - 20, 0);
        ctx.arc(mycanvas.width - 20,20,20,-Math.PI/2, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(mycanvas.width, mycanvas.height - 20);
        ctx.arc(mycanvas.width - 20,mycanvas.height - 20,20,0, Math.PI/2);
        ctx.lineTo(20, mycanvas.height);
        ctx.arc(20,mycanvas.height - 20,20,Math.PI/2,Math.PI);
        ctx.lineTo(0, 20);
        ctx.arc(20,20,20,Math.PI,-Math.PI/2);
        ctx.lineTo(30, 0);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

You can use `combo_box_title_text.contentWidth` to fit exactly the size of your text